# How to bind WSO2 on port 443 but it should run on 8445

Tags: wso2

Currently , my WSO2 is running on port 8445 .
and Mgt Console URL  is like https://devwso2.ex.com:8445 is working .
But I want to use the port 443 so that I don't want show the actual port to the user .

How to do the changes in WSO2 ???

Comment: TCP reverse proxy like haproxy should do the work.

Answer (score 1):

In the directory CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat you will find catalina-server.xml.  Below the Service tag you should see Connectors.  Update the port on the Connector to the port you want to use.  Restart the service.

```
<Service name="Catalina" className="org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.service.ExtendedStandardService">

<Connector port="80" server="WSO2 Carbon Server" ....... />

<Connector port="443" server="WSO2 Carbon Server" ..... />
```

Edit: We run Windows and this works for us.  As pointed out in comments and later answers this is not ideal for linux.

Comment: On linux you need to run a process as root to be able to bind on ports 80 or 443 what is usually very bad idea

Comment: I am using haproxy as load balancer . I have defined frontend as 443 and backend servers with port 8445 . I have added one more parameter in the <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat directory , proxyPort="443" in the catalina-server.xml. Now, I am getting 503 Service Unavailable error . Do I need to open the port 443 , on the WSO2 Identity server ???

Answer (score 1):

We usually use an http proxy implemented by any of capable product or client appliance (apache httpd, nginx, haproxy, F5, Juniper, ..)

You may see the documentation [Configuring the Proxy Server and the Load Balancer](https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/87687537)

In the CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml add `proxyPort=443` to the https Conmector configuration

Configure your preferred (or client provided) reverse proxy and you are good to go.

This is a link to the [Apache Reverse Proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html). Nginx got pretty popular, but its OSS version has some limitations

Edit: In theory (as already answered) you may configure your wso2 product to listen on 80/443 directly, but on linux you neeed to run it as root which is really not adviced (understatement).

Comment: I am using haproxy as load balancer . I have defined frontend as 443 and backend servers with port 8445 .   I have added one more parameter in the   <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat directory , proxyPort="443" in the catalina-server.xml.   Now, I am getting 503 Service Unavailable error .         Do I need to open the port 443 , on the WSO2 Identity server ???

Comment: @Prasu 503 response is usually provided by a proxy when it's unable to connect to the backend service. You should check logs. Either there is no connection, but I'd guess the ssl certificate of your server is not trusted. (authority, validity, hostname).

Answer (score 0):

I have done the changes to my haproxy and given the proxyport as 443 in WSO2 catalina-server.xml . It is working . I didn't open the port on WSo2 server, it is opened at haproxy only .